# ElasticSearch pipeline for scrapy?

Tags: elasticsearch, scrapy

I want to index my items in ElasticSearch, I found this pipeline but I don't know how to implement it https://github.com/noplay/scrapy-elasticsearch ??

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You may also wish to include some example code to help debug.

Comment: just an example or steps to implement this pipeline ?

Comment: The readme already explains how to implement the pipeline. Where is your problem?

Comment: Scrapy uses a configurable pipeline system - the docs are here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html -- hope that helps.